# Vue: контекст this у methods вызывает undefined при обращении к data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

При вызове лога получаю undefined. И вроде понятно в чём причина, что контекст this теряется, но почему неясно и как соответственно исправить.

```
<script>
         export default {
            name: "day",
            props: {day: 0, month: 0, year: 0},
            data: function () {
                return {
                    day_id: 'day_'+this.day,
                    task_id : 'task_'+ this.day,
                    nameOfTask: "Имяd", 
                    **сomment: "Ваш комментарий"**
                }
            },
            mounted () {
                
            },
            created () {
                
            },
            methods: {
                SenToServerData () {
                   **console.log(this.comment);**
                }
            },
            }
        
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`сomment` в `data` != `comment` в `methods`.
Проверяйте наличие русских букв похожих на английские (в первом случае)